# Can I use VSE result in Movie Clip Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, movie-clip-editor

I'm editing a video in VSE. Some cutting here, a new sound track there.
I would now like to use the result of my edit in VSE in Movie Clip Editor to do motion tracking.

Is that possible wihtout exporting it as a new video (and importing it again) first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use unedited clips in the motion tracker for now.

Comment: Te Movie clip editor and the VSE do not share data back and forth. You can import the results of the movie clip editor as a scene, but not the other way around.

Comment: You can add a movie clip to a VSE timeline and employ its 2D stabilisation. To do tracking you must send the movie clip to the compositor (via a different scene) then back to your VSE as a scene strip.